# Extract Subdomain from a url in Lua

Tags: nginx, lua

How do I extract a subdomain from a url in Lua?

eg. if I have a url `https://foo.bar.com/path1`, I need to to something like the following

`get_subdomain("https://foo.bar.com/path1") should return "foo"`

If possible, I'd like a solution that works with both `http` and `https` urls.
Thanks

I tried using a regex, but Lua does not support POSIX compliant Regexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried string.match?

Check this:

```
function get_subdomain(url)
  local subdomain = string.match(url, "https?://([^.]+).")
  return subdomain
end
```